# Configure database mail settings

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-mail

How can I configure database mail settings and send the mail from the database in Sharepoint created default database instance as i can not find where to configure the database mail settings from the management after login sa user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for simply how to configure database mail from management studio?  If so, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175951.aspx) should give you step-by-step instructions on configuring the server.

Answer (score 2):

In Management Studio if you connect to a server using Object Explorer, then expand your server and then expand Management, there is an item called "Database Mail."  Right-click this node and you will see various configuration options.  There are system stored procedures for some of the configuration but frankly using the UI will be much quicker than learning the stored procedure interfaces.

Comment: it is not showing there for the option of to configure database mail

Comment: So what do you see in the context menu?  Are you sure you are right-clicking the "Database Mail" item?  If you don't see this, then either you are not using SSMS 2008, your sa user is not really sa, or you are not right-clicking the right item: https://sqlblog.org/files/folders/21871/download.aspx